# Excel Macro Doesn't Copy Worksheets to new Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that I partly created and pieced together from other codes. The intent of the the macro is to search all Excel files in my desktop folder called Financials -- it has approximately 25 files -- and to copy and paste into a new document all Worksheets that have the word (State) anywhere in the name; combine those Worksheets into 1 document and save the it my desktop folder called Final.
The code only saves a blank document to my folder and doesn't execute the other code

I have tried rearranging the code sequence

```
Sub CombineState()
    Dim wbOpen As Workbook
    Dim wbNew As Workbook
    Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\johnson\Desktop\Financials"
    Dim strExtension As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    On Error Resume Next
    ChDir strPath

    strExtension = Dir("*.xlsx")

    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
    wbNew.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\johnson\Desktop\Final\Financial Metrics for State", FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal

    Do While strExtension <> ""
        Set wbOpen = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strExtension)

        Dim checkSheet As Worksheet
        For Each checkSheet In wbOpen.Worksheets
            If UCase$(checkSheet.Name) Like "*State*" Then
                checkSheet.Copy After:=wbNew.Sheets(wbNew.Sheets.Count)
                wbNew.Sheets(wbNew.Sheets.Count).Name = wbNew.Sheets(wbNew.Sheets.Count).Cells(1, 1)
            End If
        Next

        wbOpen.Close SaveChanges:=False

        strExtension = Dir
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Hypothetically speaking, if 3 documents contain State anywhere in the worksheet name, the new document will have 3 worksheets and be saved to my Final folder.

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` and start fixing the errors.

Comment: `UCase$(checkSheet.Name) Like "*State*"` is always going to be False unless you have an [Option Compare Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/option-compare-statement) statement at the start of the module. Perhaps you meant to put `Like "*STATE*"` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You were close. See the comment:

```
Sub CombineState()
    Dim wbOpen As Workbook
    Dim wbNew As Workbook
    Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\johnson\Desktop\Financials\" ' Add the backslash at the end
    Dim strExtension As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    On Error Resume Next
    ChDir strPath

    strExtension = Dir("*.xlsx")

    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
    wbNew.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\johnson\Desktop\Final\Financial Metrics for State", FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal

    Do While strExtension <> ""
        Set wbOpen = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strExtension)

        Dim checkSheet As Worksheet
        For Each checkSheet In wbOpen.Worksheets
            If UCase$(checkSheet.Name) Like "*STATE*" Then
                checkSheet.Copy After:=wbNew.Sheets(wbNew.Sheets.Count)
                wbNew.Sheets(wbNew.Sheets.Count).Name = wbNew.Sheets(wbNew.Sheets.Count).Cells(1, 1)
            End If
        Next

        wbOpen.Close SaveChanges:=False

        strExtension = Dir
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```